# Magento 1 remove currency symbol for product with custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

We would like to remove the currency symbol for products with custom options.

Our current code, displayed below, works perfect for normal products. But when a product got custom options it first show the price without the symbol and after 0.5-1.0 seconds the currency symbol is displayed.

Seems that somewhere the code for custom options activate this.

Where can we remove this?

Current price code:

```
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php $myPrice = $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false);
                        $zeros = substr($myPrice, -2);
                        if(strval($zeros) == "00") { $myPrice = substr($myPrice, 0, -2);
                        $myPrice = $myPrice . '-'; }
                        $myPrice = str_replace("€","",$myPrice);
                            //or if the € is htmlencoded
                        $myPrice = str_replace("&euro;","",$myPrice);
                        echo '<span class="price">'.$myPrice.'</span>'; ?>  
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $myPrice = $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false);
                        $zeros = substr($myPrice, -2);
                        if(strval($zeros) == "00") { $myPrice = substr($myPrice, 0, -2);
                        $myPrice = $myPrice . '-'; }
                        $myPrice = str_replace("€","",$myPrice);
                            //or if the € is htmlencoded
                        $myPrice = str_replace("&euro;","",$myPrice);
                        echo '<span class="price">'.$myPrice.'</span>'; ?>  
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php $myPrice = $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmount, false);
                        $zeros = substr($myPrice, -2);
                        if(strval($zeros) == "00") { $myPrice = substr($myPrice, 0, -2);
                        $myPrice = $myPrice . '-'; }
                        $myPrice = str_replace("€","",$myPrice);
                            //or if the € is htmlencoded
                        $myPrice = str_replace("&euro;","",$myPrice);
                        echo '<span class="price">'.$myPrice.'</span>'; ?>  
                </span>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product with some price options (like configurable product for example), there is a js script that modify the display: `js/varien/product_options.js`.

You should override this class or just some of these methods (I guess the `formatPrice` one).

Comment: Thanks! But any idea how to change the `product_options.js` file to only remove the currency symbol?

Comment: No idea. But looking at the `formatPrice` method, maybe you should try to return `price` instead of `formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat)`.

Comment: Thanks, but in that case it does also remove the max 2 decimals. So a price excl vat will be: 858.6776859504132. How can fix that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places